# How to prevent Photoshop changing the windows size if the menu bar is in auto-hide mode?

Tags: high-sierra, preferences, adobe-photoshop

Photoshop is constantly moving the window application on macOS when the menu bar overlaps it. The menu bar is set to be hidden automatically like it's shown in the image below. I'm using Photoshop CS6 (13.0.0) on macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) but I've experienced this behavior in different versions of Photoshop and macOS.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't do that on CC 2019, presumably it was fixed in an update. CS6 probably isn't aware of that pref, as it wasn't available back then.

Comment: @Tetsujin do you know why CC requires so much disk space? (above 2 GB) Is there a way to reduce that requirement?

Comment: I've never even thought about it before. My Apps folder is over 72GB… it's never bothered me whether an app wants 500MB or 4 GB. My boot drive is 1TB & I've 12TB of HD storage too, so it's simply never been a concern. Presumably it takes up that much space because that's what it needs to fit all the functionality in ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I see. I was hoping maybe there was an option to install only the basic stuff.

Comment: There's [Photoshop Elements](https://www.adobe.com/uk/products/photoshop-elements.html) which might be smaller. I've never used it so idk how much smaller or what else may be missing compared to the full version.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'll give it a try, thanks.